# Baucis mongo $push to array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, server, baucis

Is there a way to push to array using baucis?
I want to push to an array another object.

```
"data" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ee22032b4d566436edcfd9")
    }
]
```

I could do PUT to my server: *server?populate*

```
{'data.1': {obj}}
```

This will put a new object at the end but how can I push to the end of an array without specifying index?